# swift - add left padding for table cell

Tags: swift3, tablecell

I want to add left spacing for content in table cell, i wrote this :

```
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
} else {
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    cell.contentView.layoutMargins.left = 50.0
}
```

But, it is not working. Please help me !

Comment: You want all your cell's textLabel come with 50 left margins rights

Comment: Thanks your review, Nirav! I have recent edited my code block.